# Complexity of a recursive function that counts paths in graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, graph, time-complexity

I have found a function for a directed graph, which for vertices ‘u’ and ‘v’ in it, it counts all possible walks from ‘u’ to ‘v’ with exactly k edges on the walk.
The code and the algorithm are from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-possible-paths-source-destination-exactly-k-edges/). So,

```
// C++ program to count walks from u to v with exactly k edges
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Number of vertices in the graph
#define V 4

// A naive recursive function to count walks from u to v with k edges
int countwalks(int graph[][V], int u, int v, int k)
{
   // Base cases
   if (k == 0 && u == v)      return 1;
   if (k == 1 && graph[u][v]) return 1;
   if (k <= 0)                return 0;

   // Initialize result
   int count = 0;

   // Go to all adjacents of u and recur
   for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
       if (graph[u][i])  // Check if is adjacent of u
           count += countwalks(graph, i, v, k-1);

   return count;
}
```

I am trying to find and prove the complexity of this algorithm. According to the post:

> "The worst case time complexity of the above function is O(V^k) where V
>   is the number of vertices in the given graph. We can simply analyze
>   the time complexity by drawing recursion tree. The worst occurs for a
>   complete graph. In worst case, every internal node of recursion tree
>   would have exactly n children."

But, I cannot find the recursion that leads to a tree I can analyze in order to prove that this algorithm is `O(V^k)`. Also, I suppose that the best case is `Theta(1)`. Is that true? What about the average case?

Comment: P(k+1) = VP(k). Am I missing something? And yes, the best case is Θ(1). And I don't know how to talk about an average case (random graph with V(V-1)/2 edges?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a complete graph, each node is connected to each other node, so your `for` loop will make `|V|` recursive calls. This will happen at every recursive call, until `k` becomes 1, so `O(|V|^k)` recursive calls in total.

You can express it like this:

```
T(V, k) = |V|*T(V, k - 1)
        = |V|*|V|*T(V, k - 2)
        = |V|^2*|V|*T(V, k - 3)
        = ...
```

It's always `T(V, _)` because a node can be visited multiple times.

The best case is indeed `O(1)` when one of the first three if conditions fires during the first call.

The average case I'm not sure about, but it should still be pretty bad I think. Consider a linked list graph and a huge `k`: you will travel the same edges multiple times in order to get `k` to 0 or 1. This gets progressively worse as you add more paths.

Answer (score 0):

Generic "average case" analysis is a bit ill-posed in a problem like this because you have choices about how to define a "random" graph. One way is to say that every possible edge occurs with some probability p for 0 <= p <= 1 and then try to analyze average case running time in terms of p. But there are other ways to define random graphs as well. Also average case analysis is often hard. However, if you define what you mean by "average" (i.e. what does it mean to be random graph) then someone might be able to take a stab at it.